# Asynchronous AMQP producer and consumer

Tags: python, amqp, pika, kombu

I have a bidirectional AMQP service that both consumes messages from a queue and publishes to a fanout exchange. Clients, symmetrically, consume from the exchange and publish to the queue. (This isn't a chat server, but it can be easily thought of as a chat server.) Incoming and outgoing messages are not 1:1. Outgoing messages may be in response to an incoming message, or may be generated based on time or other asynchronous factors such as changes to the database.

I currently have this built in Python using Pika with a BlockingConnection, but it requires two full connections (each with one channel) and threading. Channels are not bidirectional in AMQP, and I have not found a way to manage two channels simultaneously with BlockingConnection. Time-based messages are very awkward and limited, because they are based on `connection.sleep()`. I've tried to convert this to `SelectConnection`, but am having trouble managing callbacks for two channels.

I would like to convert this into a non-threaded asynchronous system with a single connection having two channels. I am working in Python 3.5, so something based on coroutines or asyncio seems ideal. I'm also happy to leave Pika (I'm exploring Kombu, since we're already using Celery, but I still am having trouble handling both a producer and consumer; I've also looked at amqpstorm, though I'd prefer async rather than threaded). The only requirement is Python 3.5. Performance is not the most pressing concern (I expect less than 100 msg/sec); implementation simplicity and flexibility are much more important.

Is it practical in Pika (or any other Python AMQP system) to manage two channels, one in each direction?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you found a solution but there has been a [port of pika to support asyncio](https://aio-pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that may be worth checking out!